# Conservation of energy in the form of y=kx +b?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, energy-conservation, linear-algebra

I am doing an experiment on method of mixtures and specific heat capacities. During my experiment I have to use the graph as a means of finding the SHC of the subject. So I did the experiment with putting a hot subject into room temperature water. I did the experiment three times, each time changing the mass of the water in the calorimeter (independent variable), so each time the final equilibrium temperature was different (dependent variable).

Microsoft Excel will construct a linear best fit line graph, so the equation will be in the form of `y=kx+b`. *y* is the final temperature and *x* is the mass of the water. I need to form the conservation of energy equation in the form of y=kx+b. I will know *k* from the excel equation. I will use *k* to find the SHC of the subject.

How to form the equation to `y=kx+b`, so *y* is the final temperature and *x* is the mass of water?

The equation:

m<sub>w</sub> c<sub>w</sub> (T<sub>final</sub> -  T<sub>initial</sub>) + m<sub>c</sub> c<sub>c</sub> (T<sub>final</sub> -  T<sub>initial</sub>)=m<sub>s</sub> c<sub>s</sub> (T<sub>subject</sub> - T<sub>final</sub>)

m<sub>s</sub> is the mass of the subject.

m<sub>c</sub> is the mass of the calorimeter.

Comment: It's an algebra question... rewrite $\large T_{final}$ in terms of $\large m_s$ (all the other variables are constants)

Comment: put y in place of final temperature and x in place of mass of water then rearrange the terms in your straight line form ,then one can get  k and b and naturally c-subject.

Answer (score 0):

The variables in your experiment were : the mass of water in the calorimeter $m_w$ (independent variable) and the temperature rise in the calorimeter $\Delta T = T_{final} - T_{initial}$ (dependent variable).

Your equation can be written as :
$(m_w c_w + m_c c_c)\Delta T = m_s c_s (\Delta T' - \Delta T)$
$\frac{m_w}{m_s} + \frac{m_c}{m_w} \frac{c_c}{c_w} = \frac{c_s}{c_w}(\frac{\Delta T'}{\Delta T} - 1)$
where $\Delta T' = T_{subject} - T_{initial}$.

You should plot $y=\frac{m_w}{m_s}$ against $x=\frac{\Delta T'}{\Delta T}$.  This will give you a straight-line graph in the form $y=kx-b$ where the slope is $k=\frac{c_s}{c_w}$.

This actually places the dependent and independent variables on the wrong axes, but that is not an essential requirement.  I have used ratios as variables in the graph because (i) there is no need to worry about units, and (ii) ratios usually produce numbers on the order of 1 which are easier to scale appropriately.